# Caso extraño con suma y multiplicación en PHP ¿qué sucede?

Tags: php

Estaba probando importando archivos **PHP** con ***'require'*** y me he topado con algo extraño para un novato como yo en programación.

Este es el código:

***Archivo donde ejecuto las funciones de la librería:***

```
<?php 

    require 'lib/aritmetica.php';

    echo suma(1,2,3,4,5) . "<br>"; // Output => 15 Correcto
    echo multiply(1,2,3,4,5) . "<br>"; // Output => 0 ¿WTF?
?>
```

***Archivo lib/aritmetica.php:***

```
     <?php

       //Función de suma sencilla.
     function suma(...$arguments) {
       $result = 0;

       foreach($arguments as $number):
           $result +=  $number;
       endforeach;

       unset($number);

    return $result;
  };

     //Función de multiplicación sencilla.
     function multiply(...$arguments) {
       $result = 0;

       foreach($arguments as $number):
           $result *=  $number;
       endforeach;

       unset($number);

    return $result;
 };

?>
```

Las dos funciones son completamente iguales en estructura, lo único que cambia es asignar a la variable resultado con los operadores de asignación **+=** y ***=**

No entiendo porque en la función de multiplicación me sale cero ¿no está recibiendo los argumentos correctamente?

Comment: Oh vale, tiene razón, eso daría para otra pregunta, gracias.

Comment: El resultado es correcto, porque la identidad en la multiplicación es el __1__, no el 0. Es decir, 0x1=0; 0x2=0; 0x3=0; 0x4=0; 0x5=0...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tu error es muy sencillo:

```
//Función de multiplicación sencilla.
function multiply(...$arguments) {
  $result = 0;
```

Inicializas `$result` con **0**, y *cualquier número multiplicado por 0 es* **0**.

Cámbialo por `$result = 1`;

Comment: ¡Oh dios mio que fallo de lógica! Gracias jaja, creí que era algo especial del lenguaje que trataba de forma distinta la multiplicación con los argumentos.